# How to select linestrings in a geodataframe which are in a specific range of latitude

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile, multilinestring

I'm using the following dataset for my research work.

https://xfer.services.ncdot.gov/gisdot/DistDOTData/NCRoutes_SHP.zip

I'm trying to extract linestrings from the above dataset. The linestrings have to be between the latitudes -80.86 and -80.83.

First I loaded the dataset using geopandas.

```
import geopandas as gpd
graph = gpd.read_file("NCRoutes.shp")
graph = graph.to_crs(4236)
print(len(graph['geometry'])) # number of rows in geodataframe
graph.head()
```

The output-

```
373370
Division    MaintCntyC  RouteID RouteClass  RouteNumbe  RouteQuali  RouteInven  RouteName   BeginMP EndMP   RouteMaint  Shape_Leng  geometry
0   13  011 10000026011 1   26  0   0   I-26    0.000063    29.164804   System  56252.469013    MULTILINESTRING Z ((-82.53991 35.79167 0.00000...
1   14  045 10000026045 1   26  0   0   I-26    0.000000    17.459971   System  89044.485587    MULTILINESTRING Z ((-82.53591 35.44044 664.953...
2   13  057 10000026057 1   26  0   0   I-26    0.000000    12.606171   System  66456.002756    MULTILINESTRING Z ((-82.56037 35.95480 1145.01...
3   14  075 10000026075 1   26  0   0   I-26    0.000000    13.121029   System  69207.803704    LINESTRING Z (-82.34883 35.25453 565.22225, -8...
4   7   001 10000040001 1   40  0   0   I-40    0.000000    16.013000   System  84492.598738    LINESTRING Z (-79.53887 36.06290 179.46660, -7...
```

As you can see above, The `graph` geodataframe has 373370 rows. There is either a multilinestring or a linestring in each row of the `geometry` column. So I wrote the code below to extract the linestrings I need and keep them in a geodataframe `area`.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
area = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['geometry'], geometry='geometry') # geodataframe for saving roads of interest
itr = 0 # to keep track of which row I'm going through
for String in graph['geometry']: # iterating through each row in geometry column of geodataframe
    print("iterating through",itr,"th row in geodataframe")
    itr += 1
    if String.geom_type=='MultiLineString': # if the current row contains a multilinestring
        for ls in String: # iterating through linestrings in the multilinestring
            for i in range(len(ls.xy[0])): # iterating through points in the linestring
                #print("longitude:",ls.xy[0][i],"latitude:",ls.xy[1][i])
                if(-80.86<=ls.xy[0][i]<=-80.83):
                    temp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[ls]},geometry='geometry',crs=4236) #creating a temporary geodataframe for storing the road of interest
                    area = area.append(temp)
                    break # no need to keep looking if linestring is already added to area geodataframe
    else: # if the current row contains a linestring
        for i in range(len(String.xy[0])):
            if(-80.86<=String.xy[0][i]<=-80.83):
                temp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[String]},geometry='geometry',crs=4236)
                area = area.append(temp)
                break
    clear_output(wait=True)
```

But it took around 12 minutes to iterate through 150 rows in my laptop; whereas there are 373370 rows in the dataframe. So it'll take around 500 hours to iterate through the whole `graph` geodataframe in my machine. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: do you want strictly multi/linestrings that are within this range or one that intersect this range?

Comment: I want multi/linestrings within this range, including the multi/linestrings that intersect this range of latitude.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `cx`, the coordinate indexer.

```py
subset = graph.cx[:, -80.86:-80.83]
```

See more in the documentation https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Regarding MultiLinestring vs LineString, you can use `explode` before the indexing to ensure individual parts are used, not whole geometries.

```py
subset = graph.explode().cx[:, -80.86:-80.83]
```